# Проверять "Если значение не меняется в течении x секунд C#"

Tags: c#, if

У меня есть значение `public int Shields = 100;` которое если не изменяется x секунд или более, выполняется `Shields++;` . Так вот,
как проверить условие `Если значение не меняется в течении x секунд`

Comment: У вас приложение многопоточное?

Comment: Если речь идет про Unity, то это в корне меняет дело и принятый ответ неверен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime _someValueLastChangeTime;
int _someValue = 0;
public int SomeValue { 
    get { return _someValue; }
    set {
        _someValueLastChangeTime = DateTime.Now();
        _someValue = value;
    }
}
```

ну и таймер создай:

```
{
    if ( (DateTime.Now() - _someValueLastChangeTime).TotalSeconds >= 100)
        SomeValue++;
}
```

да интервал таймера выставь на время меньше секунды. Можно на 400мс, например.

Код может немного не работать т.к. вижуалки под рукой нет, но принцип именно такой должен сработать.

Comment: хранить DateTime для таких задач чревато, когда время поменяется, например, при переходе на летнее-зимнее время или просто при изменении пользователем. У `Environment.TickCount` масса своих проблем. Я остановился на статическом экземпляре StopWatch, стартующем при запуске программы.

Comment: Согласен. Но с ним кода больше, а здесь вряд ли тот уровень, что бы с этим заморачиваться. Скорее всего какая-то мелкая временная таска, которая не столкнется вообще с подобными проблемами - не доживет)